# Angular 2 Karma - can't find variable google

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, karma-jasmine

In my application I use the google API for maps, so in index.html I have :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXX"></script>
```

and with this I can simply use the google API without any other imports, like for example with this declaration:

```
infoWindow: google.maps.InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
```

Now I'm making tests using Karma + Jasmine and in my component which uses google, I have a `Can't find variable: google` error message. I get why it happens but I have no idea how I can make it work.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hey KGFMK, thanks for your answer but I don't see the answer of my issue in the 2 posts you sent. These topics are about testing maps behavious while I have completely a problem about the initialization

Comment: In the 2nd like, they were using spys.. There was an example with Backbone/Coffescript.. I thought that could be applied to your example.  In the 2nd question, the guy was also injecting elements into the page. wondered if that might solve your problem. There may be some sort of lifecycle hooks at play with your scenario too. I'll dig around a bit more and see if I can help some more.. Any chance you can post a more complete test script..

Comment: Well yeah but it still doesn't solve my issue, my google variables are in my component variables definition, not in methods, it's like: export class MyComponent { infoWindow: google.maps.InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow() }

Comment: I suspect they would get defined at some point, but it's probably due to asynchronous code...

Comment: Maybe, thanks anyway for helping!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple - there's some sort of async defer in that code.. So if you post a more complete test case, I'll have more to go on to pinpoint your error.

Comment: And you see the callback un the google example. It's setting up an element to put map into..

Comment: They also did something here with Geocoder.. that you may be able to adapt. https://kwilson.io/blog/mock-out-google-maps-geocoder-with-jasmine-spies/

Answer (score 3):

1. Create your own google-mock.js
2. Fill it with an IIFE that binds google to the window:

```
(function () {
    window.google = window.google || {
        maps: {
            Map: function () { },
            Point: function () { },
            event: {
                trigger: function () { },
                addListener: function () { }
            },
            LatLng: function () { },
            InfoWindow: function () { },
            Size: function () { },
            OverlayView: function () { },
            Marker: function () { }
        }
    };
})();
```

3. Add it to your files array in the karma.config:

```
files: ['../test/unit/google-map-mock.js']
```

You have to add to the IIFE whatever you need from the library.

Answer (score -1):

Add [@types/googlemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps) to your devDependencies:

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

Add the following code to the top of component or service in which your are using `google.maps`:

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

Comment: @guigui have you had a chance to try this out?